# How to set button at bottom if scroll enabled?

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I am working on **Design** in android.The requirement is when i have more than **10 fields** in an s`croll layout` the button should align below to the end of `scroll view` and if i have only two fields in a layout it should align at bottom of the screen static.Now the issue which i am facing here is if i have less than 3 fields my `Textview` button came to top if there is no scroll and its was not aligning at bottom of the Screen.I am attaching my **xml** here please let me know some suggestions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/signupRootLay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/background" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#b3000000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pageCountParentLay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstpageTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_bg_with_low_contrast_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/page_1"
            android:textColor="@color/high_contrast_color"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondPageTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_bg_with_low_contrast_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/page_2"
            android:textColor="@color/high_contrast_color"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thirdPageTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_bg_with_low_contrast_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/page_3"
            android:textColor="@color/high_contrast_color"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fourthPageTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_bg_with_low_contrast_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/page_4"
            android:textColor="@color/high_contrast_color"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleParentLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pageCountParentLay"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/leftLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/secondary_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pageTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/page_title_1"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_color"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/rightLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/secondary_color" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_below="@+id/titleParentLay">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/parentLay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/si_fields" />

            <include layout="@layout/si_exi_card_layout" />

            <include layout="@layout/password_layout" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nextTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/button_low_contrast_color_bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/next_label"
                android:textColor="@color/high_contrast_color"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to wrap scrollview with linearlayout and put yout button after the scrollview, I think you can achieve what you want. If you want your button to be visible statically on the bottom of the *screen* try to to the same in relative layout

Comment: Thank you i will try that@BerkayTutal

Comment: It wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Add below line in `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:fillViewport="true"/>
```

Comment: last two include layouts are gone if i applied this fillviewport and also the textview button is not inside the scroll view

Answer (score 0):

Just put the button outside the scrollview and thats it.
Example like this:

```html
<ScrollView>
  <RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
<Button />
```

Comment: I just need the button inside the scroll if fields are more and outside the scroll if fields are less and my all fields are dynamic